# Python regex on wikitext template

Tags: python, regex, wikitext

I'm trying to remove line breaks with Python from wikitext templates of the form:

```
{{cite web
|title=Testing
|url=Testing
|editor=Testing
}}
```

The following should be obtained with re.sub:

```
{{cite web|title=Testing|url=Testing|editor=Testing}}
```

I've been trying with Python regex for hours, yet haven't succeeded at it. For example I've tried:

```
while(re.search(r'\{cite web(.*?)([\r\n]+)(.*?)\}\}')):
     textmodif=re.sub(r'\{cite web(.*?)([\r\n]+)(.*?)\}\}', r'{cite web\1\3}}', textmodif,re.DOTALL)
```

But it doesn't work as expected (even without the while loop, it's not working for the first line break).

I found this similar question but it didnt help: [Regex for MediaWiki wikitext templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982251/regex-for-mediawiki-wikitext-templates) . I'm quite new at Python so please don't be too hard on me :-)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch on newline matching for `.`; it does *not* match a newline otherwise:

```
re.search(r'\{cite web(.*?)([\r\n]+)(.*?)\}\}', inputtext, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

You have multiple newlines spread throughout the text you want to match, so matching just one set of consecutive newlines is not enough.

From the [`re.DOTALL` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S):

> Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything *except* a newline.

You could use one `re.sub()` call to remove all newlines within the `cite` stanza in one go, without a loop:

```
re.sub(r'\{cite web.*?[\r\n]+.*?\}\}', lambda m: re.sub('\s*[\r\n]\s*', '', m.group(0)), inputtext, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

This uses a nested regular expression to remove all whitespace with at least one newline in it from the matched text.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = '''\
... {{cite web
... |title=Testing
... |url=Testing
... |editor=Testing
... }}
... '''
>>> re.search(r'\{cite web(.*?)([\r\n]+)(.*?)\}\}', inputtext, flags=re.DOTALL)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10f335458>
>>> re.sub(r'\{cite web.*?[\r\n]+.*?\}\}', lambda m: re.sub('\s*[\r\n]\s*', '', m.group(0)), inputtext, flags=re.DOTALL)
'{{cite web|title=Testing|url=Testing|editor=Testing}}\n'
```